# Should I use Firebase with react. Alternative to Firebase as backend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I am taking this course building a chat app with react and firebase as backend. The problem is when I got to connecting react, redux, and firebase the whole process became so complex that got me wondering what's the point of Libraries, Frameworks, and SDK if not to make the development process easier or faster at least. Please is there other alternatives to using Firebase as backend with react. (Without so many add-ons, helper-functions, and enhancers that I need to connect)

Comment: You're finding firebase too difficult to learn. Don't give up, it saves you a lot of time when you want to implement functionality like authentication and databases. If you actually want users to create accounts on your app, and save/ load data, its a real time saver. If there's one thing you can cut out of learning for now (maybe forever), its redux & react-redux-firebase.

Comment: And general advice: don't try to learn a library that you don't know what it does. Because then you can't justify learning it, and it just overwhelms you. Just learn react to start with.

Comment: The alternative is to do everything that `Firebase` provides on your own, which will be a lot more difficult, time consuming, and it will require more work. Or use another service that's `Firebase-`like, but that doesn't mean that it will be either simpler than what `Firebase` already provides - they all exist for a reason and should be chosen based on your requirements - https://blog.back4app.com/2019/10/29/best-firebase-alternatives/.

Comment: Of course am fully aware it all takes some connecting, I am only asking if someone has used other alternate service that isn't as rigorous as react-redux-firebase. And you're right it's not necessary firebase, it's react-redux @BenB

Comment: And I only ask, Am not planning to stop learning it, I actually finished the connecting with the project before thinking maybe there are other services with less complex builds

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few alternatives: PubNub etc.. but all of them will require some setup and config to make it work with react. firebase by itself is not complicated, but make it work with react piles up the complexity a bit.

Just try it a bit more and once you are done with config and setup it way more fun. Here is a simple example to try: https://www.codementor.io/@yurio/all-you-need-is-react-firebase-4v7g9p4kf

Answer (score 0):

The title doesn't explain your problem. I think its not firebase thats getting in the way, but in-fact redux/ react-redux-firebase.

If you're just learning react, you should not be trying redux. Redux has a steep learning curve, and will get in the way of you understanding the real part of react. Kent C. Dodds has [said](https://kentcdodds.com/workshops/react-hooks):

> guess what, you probably don't need a library like Redux anymore

This might be *speculation*, but redux might not be as popular in the future, so you might not even have to learn it in the future. You can just use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). People often abuse redux.

Comment: There's no problem actually, just wanted a tip or preferences on such related service.